# How to use Apportable to build with a custom package name?

Tags: android, apk, apportable

I'm trying to submit my APK to google play, but the package name must begin with lowercase letters, etc, so I'm wondering how I can specify the package name when using apportable to build the APK. (i.e., what do I write in terminal?) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the application identifier to use for Android in .approj/configuration.json. In the config section of that file, just uncomment out "APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER": "", and enter in the application id you wish to use for Android, such as com.yourcompany.yourapp.

Comment: you could specify it also as an environment variable, like `APPLICATION_IDENTIFIER=com.example.test apportable build`

Answer (score 0):

The package name generated by Apportable relies on the Bundle Identifier that you wrote your Xcode project. My Bundle Identifier began with a *capital letter*, and therefore I was not able to upload my APK due to naming errors. In order to change your package name, simply change the Bundle Identifier in your Xcode project, and Apportable will make the APK with the corresponding package name. For me, I just made the first letter of my Bundle Identifier lowercase, and it was a success.